# Get hidden radio button value and insert form with ajax

Tags: jquery, html

I have two radio buttons where user can select the user type. The radio buttons are hidden and I am using images instead of the original design. What I am trying to do is to set the default value of the radio button checked onLoad, so the user doesn't have to make an extra click. I tried setting the radio button checked in HTML, but the value is not being passed, since I have the var value; as a parameter for formData.

### HTML

```
<div class="form-group" id="radio-image">
    <div class="cc-selector">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
            <input id="hoidja" type="radio" class="account" name="accountType" value="hoidja" />
            <label class="usertype hoidja" id="hoidja" for="hoidja" style="-webkit-filter: brightness(1) grayscale(0.6) opacity(0.9);"></label>
            <b class="user_type_form">HOIDJA</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
            <input id="pere" type="radio" class="account" name="accountType" value="pere" checked/>
            <label class="usertype pere" for="pere" style="-webkit-filter: brightness(1) grayscale(0) opacity(1);"></label>
            <b class="user_type_form">PERE</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var value
            $("input:radio[name=accountType]").click(function() {
                value = $(this).val();
                console.log(value);
            });

            $("#btn-signup").on("click", function(){
                var formData = {
                    'formEmail'                : $('#formEmail').val(),
                    'formPassword'             : $('#formPassword').val(),
                    'accountType'              : value,
                    't_and_c'                  : $('#t_and_c').val(),
                    'formFirstName'            : $('#formFirstName').val(),
                    'formLastName'             : $('#formLastName').val(),

                };
                ////COMES REST OF THE AJAX
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For RadioButtons, instead of `.click` it's better to use `.change` event(not compulsory) and trigger it on page load as well.

```
var value = '';
$("input:radio[name=accountType]").change(function() {
   value = $("input:radio[name=accountType]:checked").val(); //OR $(this).val();
   console.log(value);
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: @raqulka..happy to help you..:)